# Google sign account on Firebase test lab

Tags: firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am using Firebase test lab to automate ui test.
Is there any possible way to login my own test account instead of test account ?
It seems that Firebase support custom login but not work for me.

> Custom sign-in: If you provide test account credentials, you need to
>   tell Robo test where to enter them, and also provide those
>   credentials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require a Google account to log in, your only option is to allow Robo to use its own account.

If your app allows some sort of custom username/password login using form fields that you created yourself, then you can arrange for those values to be entered by configuration, as the documentation is saying.  This is not going to be a Google account.